# Adding the current time into a specific section on my page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I made a `div id="time"` on my HTML file and positioned it so that the current time can show up on the upper left side of my website inside the border I made. So I want the current time to show up inside that border on the upper left side of my website that I made but have trouble doing so:

HTML file:

```
    <div id="time">

    </div>
```

My js file:

```
var time = document.getElementById("time")

var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

if (minutes < 10)
    minutes = "0" + minutes

var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
}

document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")
```

The current time does successfully show up but it does not show up in the location that I want it to (it shows up all the way on the bottom of the page). Perhaps there is something wrong with the DOM?

Comment: It's basically because after declaring hook/reference to element with "time" ID - `var time` - you don't use it at all! You should refer to `time` variable and add content with "computed" time using `innerHTML` property.

Comment: You  should mark some answer as correct..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var time = document.getElementById("time")

var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
suffix = "PM";
hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
hours = 12;
}

time.innerHTML = "<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>";
```

```html
<div id="time">

</div>
```

Use `time.innerHTML = '...'` to show in the place where your div is located.

**Some words about document.write()**

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)**: The method document.write() allows you to insert HTML into the page while the
>   page is being loaded. You can have something like the following code:
>
> ```
> <p>It is now
>     <script>document.write("<em>" + new Date() + "</em>"); </script>
> </p>
> ```
>
> This is the same as if you had the date directly in the source of the
>   HTML document as follows:
>
> ```
> <p>It is now 
>     <em>Fri Apr 26 2013 16:55:16 GMT-0700 (PDT)</em> 
> </p>
> ```
>
> Note, that you can only use document.write() while the page is being
>   loaded. If you try it after page load, **it will replace the content of
>   the whole page**. It's rare that you would need document.write(), and if
>   you think you do, try an alternative approach. The ways to modify the
>   contents of the page provided by DOM Level 1 are preferred and are
>   much more flexible.

Comment: Also take a look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) instead of manipulating strings manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.. All you had to do is to put the document.getElementById() after the div id="time". It works well.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
suffix = "PM";
hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
hours = 12;
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="time" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;">123
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML="<b>" + hours + ":" +minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>";
    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the var *time*, but you didn't use it. Set *time*.innerHTML value as the date instead of document.write:

```
time.innerHTML = "<b>"+ hours +":"+ minutes +" "+ suffix +"</b>";
```

This way, you can put the div with id "time" anywhere you want the date to show up on the page